# Geometry Shader support in Mesa i965 DRI for Intel SandyBridge Hardware

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader, mesa

I am trying to run the GS demo code of Mesa from here :
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/demos/tree/src/gs, by git cloning this:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/demos

However, I get the error as "needs GL_ARB_geometry_shader4 extension".

I am not that up to date with how the Mesa development is going on, but it
seems that GL_ARB_geometry_shader4 extension is not available for Mesa?

As per this link:
http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-dev/2014-August/065692.html, it
shows Geometry Shader support has been added to Intel SandyBridge platform.

I also came across this link:
http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/MissingFunctionality/, which indicates that
the GL_ARB_geometry_shader4 extension is a "Missing Functionality".

Considering all of this, how should I proceed to write my applications with
geometry shaders using Mesa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this extension is only supported on Nvidia GPU's which is why you can't use it

Edit : You don't need this extension to use Geometry Shaders. The example here

http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial27/tutorial27.html

Should work perfectly fine on intel GPU's

Comment: If it were only an Nvidia extension, then it would have been named GL_NV_geometry_shader4 isn't it?

The reason it is ARB "blessed" is that it can be used for other GPUs also.

Comment: This extension was approved before it became core. See the URL attached. https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader_Examples.